# How to catch http status errors by using @ControllerAdvice in Java-config?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, exception

I have such contoller to handle exceptions:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalErrorController {

public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "errors/default";

@ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
public ModelAndView exception(Exception e) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
    mav.addObject("name", e.getClass().getSimpleName());
    mav.addObject("message", e.getMessage());

    return mav;
}

}
```

Any exception are catched, but how can I catch 404 and others http status errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. As I usere Java-config approach than at the end I get smth like that:

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { JPAConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {

    String servletName = super.getServletName();
    Assert.hasLength(servletName, "getServletName() may not return empty or null");

    WebApplicationContext servletAppContext = super.createServletApplicationContext();
    Assert.notNull(servletAppContext,
            "createServletApplicationContext() did not return an application " +
            "context for servlet [" + servletName + "]");

    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);

    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = servletContext.addServlet(servletName, dispatcherServlet);
    Assert.notNull(registration,
            "Failed to register servlet with name '" + servletName + "'." +
            "Check if there is another servlet registered under the same name.");

    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping(getServletMappings());
    registration.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSupported());

    super.customizeRegistration(registration);
}

}
```

And use ControllerAdvice+ExceptionHandler annotations

Answer (score 0):

`@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` only catch Exceptions thrown by code that is actually patched through to the dispatcherservlet. If a request never makes it into your controller classes, this won't work.

Instead, you will have to do an error code mapping in your web.xml, like this:

```
<error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

You can then map the URL /404 to display any view with any content you want. The user will never actually be redirected to that URL or know it exists. The controller method mapped to /404 can also contain an Exception parameter.

Comment: I know about this solution, but problem is that project used Java-configuration approach. So its not suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `@ExceptionHandler` to catch exception that are thrown before or after the controller.

But you can register a custom `HandlerExceptionResolver`. A simple way would be to just extend `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`, but you can also configure a `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` and use the `order` attribute to give it prioriry over the default.